# Acceleration varies inversely with 3rd power of displacement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, differentiation

> **Question.** A particle is moving in a straight line. Displacement $x$ and time $t$ of the particle are related by the equation
>   $$x^2=at^2+2bt+c~;~\text{where }a,b,c\text{ are constants.}$$
>   Prove that, the acceleration of the particle is directly proportional to $x^{-3}.$

*Progress.* We have
\begin{align*}
x^2&=at^2+2bt+c
\\x&=\sqrt{at^2+2bt+c}
\\\frac{dx}{dt}&=\frac{2at+2b}{2\sqrt{at^2+2bt+c}}=\frac{at+b}{\sqrt{at^2+2bt+c}}
\\\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}&=\frac{a\sqrt{at^2+2bt+c}-(at+b)\times\frac{at+b}{\sqrt{at^2+2bt+c}}}{at^2+2bt+c}
\\&=\frac{a\sqrt{at^2+2bt+c}-\frac{(at+b)^2}{\sqrt{at^2+2bt+c}}}{at^2+2bt+c}
\\&=\frac{ax-\frac{(at+b)^2}{x}}{x^2}
\\&=\frac{a}{x}-\frac{(at+b)^2}{x^3}
\\\implies\text{acceleration of the particle }&=\frac{a}{x}-\frac{(at+b)^2}{x^3}
\end{align*}
If $\frac{a}{x}$ was constant, then the statement would be proved. But, $x$ is a variable. Hence, the statement is not proved.

**P.S.** This is what I did to solve the problme. Did I make any error in calculation? Or the mistake is in some other step? Please tell me where I am wrong.

**Edit.** Thank you, user 1583209!

We have \begin{align*}
\text{acceleration of the particle }&=\frac{a}{x}-\frac{(at+b)^2}{x^3}
\\&=\frac{ax^2-(at+b)^2}{x^3}
\\&=\frac{a(at^2+2bt+c)-(a^2t^2+2abt+b^2)}{x^3}
\\&=\frac{ac-b^2}{x^3}
\\\implies\text{acceleration of the particle }&\propto x^{-3}
\end{align*}
Thus, the statement is proved.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked your calculation, but if $\frac{a}{x}$ was constant, the acceleration would **not be** proportional to $x^{-3}$ because you still have a time dependence in the numerator (and $x$ and $t$ are not independent of each other)!

However, assuming the calculation is correct you can rewrite your result as:

$$\mathrm{acceleration}=\frac{a}{x}-\frac{(at+b)^2}{x^3}\\
=\frac{ax^2-(at+b)^2}{x^3}
=\frac{a(at^2+2bt+c)-(at+b)^2}{x^3}=\frac{ac-b^2}{x^3}$$

which is indeed proportional to $x^{-3}$ because $a,b,c$ are constants.

Comment: I would argue that even if the numerator did contain time dependence, it would still be true that "the acceleration is directly proportional to x^-3". Such a statement indicates the form of the function with respect to x, but personally I don't feel that you can assume that implies it must be independent of t. We say the Newtonian force of gravity is inversely proportional to the square of the distance, but does this preclude it from being proportional to the product of the masses?

Comment: @electronpusher: I disagree.  $x$ and $t$ are **not independent** but related through $x^2=at^2+2bt+c$, so if you have a time dependence in the end you could always substitute an $x$ dependence for it. In your example of gravity, the masses and the distance are independent of each other, i.e. the mass of the bodies does not change if you move them closer or further apart.

Comment: Excellent point, that slipped my mind!